# What exactly is the purpose of File name patterns when refactoring in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

This option shows up in several different places such as when renaming a package or a class in Eclipse. Pretty sure it's something fairly simple but I was curious to know how it works.

This is Eclipse's documentation on rename https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-35c.htm ...but couldn't find what I was looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern specifies what non-Java files are searched for the name.

For example you might specify `*.xml` to look for the name in all XML files.

One use for this is in plug-in development where you might just want to search `plugin.xml` for the name. Or `*.e4xmi` to look for the name in e4 application fragments.